# numpy loads array as a single row of data instead of a column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a text file 'b1.txt' that looks like this (each number on its own line):

```
-2.757787776118426848e+00
2.192856759293771773e+00
-8.147814565506505957e-01
5.499176285643345707e-01
1.442480424631280123e+00
-9.951075006377330112e-01
-2.660893783465616558e+00
-3.820339505995917762e+00
6.754582328966165505e-01
2.820773547343322640e+00
1.667895668681955712e+00
2.121780764113355922e+00
2.544511699048843667e+00
1.964173756617895172e+00
-4.799149921138656794e-02
-1.319262364568441370e+00
```

When I read this data into my program using the following code:

```
filelocation = open('b1.txt', 'r')
b1 = numpy.loadtxt('b1.txt')
filelocation.close()
print ("B1 Data")
print (b1)
```

I get the following output:

```
B1 Data

[-2.76  2.19 -0.81  0.55  1.44 -1.   -2.66 -3.82  0.68  2.82  1.67  2.12
  2.54  1.96 -0.05 -1.32]
```

The b1 array is being loaded as a single row of data (e.g. b1(1,16)) instead of a single column (e.g. b1(16,1)).  This is messing up my matrix multiplication functions later in the program.  All my other arrays (eg a (4,16) array) are loaded properly, Why isn't this array being loaded as a column?

For example:  I have an array of data that looks like this in the text file:

```
7.058823529411765163e-01 3.968253968253968034e-02 8.695652173913043237e-02 6.666666666666666297e-01
8.823529411764705621e-01 5.555555555555555247e-02 1.086956521739130405e-01 6.666666666666666297e-01
7.647058823529411242e-01 1.190476190476190410e-01 1.956521739130434867e-01 6.666666666666666297e-01
9.411764705882352811e-01 2.142857142857142738e-01 2.391304347826087029e-01 6.666666666666666297e-01
6.470588235294117974e-01 4.682539682539682557e-01 2.826086956521738913e-01 6.666666666666666297e-01
7.647058823529411242e-01 4.682539682539682557e-01 5.217391304347825942e-01 6.666666666666666297e-01
5.882352941176470784e-01 6.190476190476190688e-01 4.347826086956521618e-01 6.666666666666666297e-01
7.647058823529411242e-01 8.333333333333333703e-01 7.826086956521739468e-01 1.000000000000000000e+00
7.647058823529411242e-01 8.730158730158730229e-01 1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 8.260869565217391353e-01 1.000000000000000000e+00
```

and it gets loaded to look like this:

```
[[0.71 0.04 0.09 0.67]
 [0.88 0.06 0.11 0.67]
 [0.76 0.12 0.2  0.67]
 [0.94 0.21 0.24 0.67]
 [0.65 0.47 0.28 0.67]
 [0.76 0.47 0.52 0.67]
 [0.59 0.62 0.43 0.67]
 [0.76 0.83 0.78 1.  ]
 [0.76 0.87 1.   1.  ]
 [1.   1.   0.83 1.  ]]
```

My single column array should load to look like this:

```
[-2.76  
2.19 
-0.81  
0.55  
1.44 
-1.   
-2.66 
-3.82  
0.68  
2.82  
1.67  
2.12
2.54 
1.96 
-0.05 
-1.32]
```

Comment: Seems like the data is loaded fine. Can you give an example of a file you claim to be loaded correctly? Also you can use b1.T to transpose the list

Comment: I edited my original post to include an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transpose the (1,16) array to get a (16,1) array.

`b1 = numpy.transpose(b1)`

or even transpose it immediately on load.

`b1 = numpy.transpose(numpy.loadtxt('b1.txt'))`

As for why `np.loadtxt()` is reading the data in the way it is, it probably has something to do with the implementation. It is easy enough to transpose the row vector into a column vector so there isn't a parameter to specify the orientation on load.

EDIT: Upon seeing your example of two-dimension arrays being loaded properly, it likely has something to do with the delimiters. In your 2-d arrays, the "space" whitespace is being used to delimit elements in the inner array, while the "newline" whitespace is being used to delimit elements of the outer array. Since your 1-d array only has "newline" whitespace, the loading machinery gives you a 1-d array, of dimension (16,). This cannot be transposed. You will need to `b1 = b1.reshape(16,1)` to get your desired column vector

Comment: Can you `print(b1.shape)` and see what it shows? I suspect it will show `(16,)` which means it is 1-d and therefore is no distinction between row vs. column. If you want to get that distinction, you need to do something like `b1 = b1.reshape(16,1)`. That will give you your desired column vector

Comment: You are correct!  The shape printed out as (16,) indicating a 1-d array.  This was surprising to me because in the beginning of the program I had initialized the array as (16,1), but I guess this was not retained when the file was loaded.  Thanks, much.  This solved my problems - I used the reshape routine and it fixed everything.  Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

```
In [127]: txt = """-2.757787776118426848e+00
     ...: 2.192856759293771773e+00
     ...: -8.147814565506505957e-01
     ...: 5.499176285643345707e-01
             ...
     ...: -4.799149921138656794e-02
     ...: -1.319262364568441370e+00"""

In [128]: data = np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines())
In [129]: data.shape
Out[129]: (16,)
```

But look at `loadtxt` docs.  There's a `ndmin` parameter.

```
In [130]: data = np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), ndmin=2)
In [131]: data.shape
Out[131]: (16, 1)
```

The default behavior is to squeeze dimensions of size 1, either a 1 row file, or in your case a 1 column file:

```
ndmin : int, optional
    The returned array will have at least `ndmin` dimensions.
    Otherwise mono-dimensional axes will be squeezed.
    Legal values: 0 (default), 1 or 2.
```

In `numpy`, 1d arrays are common.  Note for example, `np.dot` has provision for handling 1d arrays.   It is easy to add a size one dimension, either with `reshape` or `arr[:,None]` syntax.

`np.genfromtxt` is generally more powerful than `loadtxt`, but I don't see an equivalent `ndmin`.  Looks like you have add the dimension yourself.

```
In [137]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines())
In [138]: data.shape
Out[138]: (16,)
In [139]: data[:,None].shape
Out[139]: (16, 1)
```